# Xamarin Forms ListView not working as intended on ios

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to make a simple listView with Xamarin Forms. The listView works in android, but on iOS i get a bugg where the content is missplaced over the cells. See my image and code below:

[image]

This is my code:

Page

```
public class TablePage
{
    public static Page GetTablePage ()
    {
        //Get NewsItems to populate listView
        var NewsItemList = DataAccessLayer.GetNewsItemList ();

        ListView listView = new ListView {
            ItemsSource = NewsItemList,
            ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate (typeof(NewsCell))
        };

        return new ContentPage { 
            Content = new StackLayout {
                Children = {
                    listView
                }
            },
            Title = "Table",
        };
    }
}
```

Cell:

```
public class NewsCell : ViewCell
    {
        public NewsCell ()
        {
            var headerLabel = new Label();
            var contentLabel = new Label();

            headerLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "header");
            contentLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "content");

            var s = new StackLayout();
            s.Padding = 20;
            s.Children.Add(headerLabel);
            s.Children.Add(contentLabel);

            this.View = s;
        }
    }
```

DataAccessLayer for items:

```
public static List<NewsItem> GetNewsItemList()
{
    List<NewsItem> NewsItemList = new List<NewsItem> ();
    NewsItemList.Add(new NewsItem { header = "News1", content = "content1"});
    NewsItemList.Add(new NewsItem { header = "News2", content = "content2"});
    NewsItemList.Add(new NewsItem { header = "News3", content = "content3"});
    NewsItemList.Add(new NewsItem { header = "News4", content = "content4"});
    return NewsItemList;
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I'd recommend reducing the `Padding` on your `StackLayout` - either that or setting the `RowHeight` of your `ListView` to be larger to accomodate all that `Padding`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is the padding you've used is 20px, much too large.

Take a look at [this article](http://www.htmldog.com/guides/css/beginner/margins/) to see what Padding is - it is the space between your container element and the space where child elements are laid out.

In this case you're putting 20px on either side, so the `headerLabel` starts 20px below the top, takes something like 20px itself and the `contentLabel` starts under that. At the same time the ListView still has its default row height, looks like something around 42px, so the `contentLabel` starts at offset of 40px and therefore over the next cell.

You can **change your Padding** to `s.Padding = new Thickness(20,2,20,2);` so that you get 20px on left and right but only 2 on top and bottom.

---

You will also notice that your ListView starts from the top of the screen and the iOS bar covers some of the content. To fix that apply a similar padding trick to the content page itself:

```
if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.iOS)
    this.Padding = new Thickness (0, 20, 0, 0);
```